# Getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError exception while using the below Recursive method

Tags: java, recursion, out-of-memory

[image]Basically below method is traversing through nodes and creating a graph like structure. More that 400K objects are being created resulting in OutOfMemoryError. Could someone help to optimize the below code.

**Method :**

```
    private static PolicyNodeInfo[] mapPolicySteps(PolicyTreatmentNodeInfo fromObj)
 {

    List<PolicyNodeInfo> tmpList = new ArrayList<PolicyNodeInfo>();
    PolicyTreatmentNodeInfo[] childrens = fromObj.getChildrenPolicyInfo(); 
    // Get object policy node children

    if(childrens != null) //if there are no children return empty list
    {
        for(PolicyTreatmentNodeInfo child : childrens) 
        //for each children map the object and recursively go over his children
        {
            if(null!=child)
             {
                if(X3ServerUtil.isStringNotEmptyNotNull(child.getStepName())&& 
                   !child.getStepName().startsWith("Dummy")) 
             //case child is not null (edge) or it's not non operation step (need to ignore)
                    {   
                    int index = tmpList.size();
                    tmpList.add(insertStep(child)); //insert current node

                    tmpList.get(index).setPolicyTreatmentNodeInfoList(mapPolicySteps(child)); 
                    //insert recursively all child nodes
                }
                else
                {
                handleDummyChildNodeInsertion(tmpList, child);
                }
            }
        }
    }
        return tmpList.toArray(new PolicyNodeInfo[tmpList.size()]);
}
```

> Exception : (Stack.java:23)
>   weblogic.kernel.ThreadLocalStack$StackInitialValue.initialValue(ThreadLocalStack.java:159)
>   at
>   weblogic.kernel.FinalThreadLocal$FinalThreadStorage.(FinalThreadLocal.java:208)
>   at weblogic.kernel.AuditableThread.(AuditableThread.java:13)
>   Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

Graph Structure is similar to below one , with 49 nodes. And due to multiple path possible , method is being called more than 400K times..

Comment: Exception added in question/post.

Comment: please post that as a part of the question, not as a comment

Comment: How many elements are you trying to create? do remember, for each method call you re-declare and instantiate your tmpList, ... variables, which 'll cause your system to run out of resources

Comment: Basically the graph contains 49 element only , but one node can be Successor of multiple node.

Comment: how many times are you (recursively or not) calling that method?

Comment: Added a graph image in the post. There are only 49 nodes , but due to multiple path possible for traversing the graph , method is being called more than 400K times.

Comment: so you have tmpList as variable in memory over 400K times (and that's not the only one). I would be surprised if your code didn't crash, honestly

Comment: Agreed , 400K+ objects will certainly lead to huge memory consumption and eventually lead to code crash. That is what we are trying to optimize here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help. Have been trying to resolve the issue and came up with below solution, which is working fine. Posting the answer below. :)

```
  //Created a class level hashmap
public static Map<String,PolicyNodeInfo> executedElementMap=new HashMap<String,PolicyNodeInfo>();  

// Whichever node is being traversed is stored in the map.
// Before Traversing any node , just checking whether the node has already been traversed , if traversed just add the node and skip the traversing.

private static PolicyNodeInfo[] mapPolicySteps(PolicyTreatmentNodeInfo fromObj)

{
    List<PolicyNodeInfo> tmpList = new ArrayList<PolicyNodeInfo>();
    PolicyTreatmentNodeInfo[] childrens = fromObj.getChildrenPolicyInfo(); // Get object policy node children
    if(childrens != null) //if there are no children return empty list
    {
        for(PolicyTreatmentNodeInfo child : childrens) //for each children map the object and recursively go over his children
        {
            if(null!=child)
                {
                Boolean isNodeTraversed= executedElementMap.containsKey(child.getStepName());
                  if(!isNodeTraversed)
                  {
                    executedElementMap.put(child.getStepName(), child);
                    if(X3ServerUtil.isStringNotEmptyNotNull(child.getStepName())&& !child.getStepName().startsWith(PREFIX_FOR_NON_OPERATION_STEP)) //case child is not null (edge) or it's not non operation step (need to ignore)
                    {   
                        int index = tmpList.size();
                        tmpList.add(insertStep(child)); //insert current node
                        tmpList.get(index).setPolicyTreatmentNodeInfoList(mapPolicySteps(child)); //insert recursively all child nodes
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        handleDummyChildNodeInsertion(tmpList, child);
                    }
                 }  
                 else{
                      tmpList.add(insertStep(child));  
                     }
              }
        }
    }
    return tmpList.toArray(new PolicyNodeInfo[tmpList.size()]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is dangerous for traversing big datasets as the stack memory is practically not under your control. (In other words: I learned recursion at school being a "most elegant" solution and as "don't do" at university - go figure...)

To eliminate this, use a suitable data structure to unroll, e.g. a queue along these lines:

```
Deque<MyObject> queue = ...
queue.push(rootElement);
while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
    MyObject currentElement = queue.poll();
    // ... process current element
    // and in the end: push children
    currentElement.getChildren().forEach(child -> queue.push(child));
}
```

For depth-first traversal use a stack instead (i.e. `pop()` instead of `poll()`);

If this still gives you out of memory errors, you'll either have to increase your heap-space or use a different approach alltogether.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line `tmpList.get(index).setPolicyTreatmentNodeInfoList(mapPolicySteps(child));`
the order of the calls here is 
`mapPolicySteps(child)` gets called first and **only** when it returns `.setPolicyTreatmentNodeInfoList(/*Whatever returns from mapPolicySteps(child)*/)` is being called.
That creates a LOT of stack frames that waiting for the `mapPolicySteps` function to end.

You need to figure out a way such that `mapPolicySteps` function will be call last.
(Known as [Tail call / Tail recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call))

Answer (score -1):

```
 I have faced same and resolved by using Garbage collector. There is multiple way to resolve this issue.
 1. Define scope of data members and make sure garbage collector is in picture.
 2. increase java memory for your Environment.
 https://www.wikihow.com/Increase-Java-Memory-in-Windows-7
```

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer. about GC, the developer can't control when it runs, it's the JVM that decide when and when not to run it. Increasing memory won't do you any good if you are stuck in an infinite loop which keeps instantiating new variables, nor will the GC, for that matter, if none of those variables are ever set to null.

Comment: Sorry... I haven't reputation to comment. So did same and we can call forcefully garbage collector.

Comment: No, we can't. we can "request" for the GC to run, but that doesn't mean it actually will run.

Comment: But, even if we could: the problem is that the variables in this case are not eligible for GC, so, even if it runs, it won't collect these, and they will continue to take up memory